# In eclipse, How to combine handler events and action of the actionSet

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin which contains popup menu (using the org.eclipse.ui.handlers extension) main menu item (using the org.eclipse.ui.actionSet extension).
Therefore I had to implement both the execution method (Object execute(ExecutionEvent event)) and run method (void run(IAction action)).
How do I combine those methods and implement only one execute method.
My plugin xml is

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) {
    String parameter = event.getParameter("parameter-key");
    combine(parameter);
    return null;
}

public void run(IAction action) {
    combine("");
}

protected void combine(String parameter) {

}
```